# Merging netcdf files into one and making time series

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

I have 18 years TRMM daily rainfall data (6573 .nc4 files). I need to combine all those .nc4 files into one and to organize them as a time series data for any specific location. How can I get rid of this?

I have tried nccopy, cdo, free netCDF extractor is not support these operation. I am a new researcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to do this with `python` and [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/). It is very easy to build up a script doing this:

```
import xarray
from datetime import datetime

time_delta = datetime(2018, 1, 1)-datetime(2000, 1, 1)
list_of_file_names = [f"{day}.nc" for day in range(time_delta.days)]

all_data = xarray.open_mfdataset(list_of_file_names)
```

An alternative would be using `cdo`. You can find an example here [example](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/1/topics/908)

Comment: I have done it using CDO, TIA